# Calling makefile in a subdirectory

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I have a source code folder structure as follows

```
src
 |-tests
 |-abc
```

I have a makefile in `src` which has a target called `tests`. `tests` has its own `makefile` which it uses to compile the source code into binary.(multiple targets).All that is managed by the Makefile in the test directory.

My `src` make file has the following targets.

```
all: main tests

main: $(DEPENDENCY IN SRC and ABC)
   command

tests: ??
     make -C tests
```

What dependancy can I specify for tests target in the main Makefile.. I don't want this Makefile to be aware of the source files in the tests folder.

Comment: Does the main Makefile know the default target of `tests/Makefile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the target as [`PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) meaning that `make` will not check for any produced file. Instead it just **always** executes the rule, letting the secondary call to `make` to decide what needs to be built.

Think about this: What happens if you have an aditional file `src/tests`? `make` will notice that the file already exists and, as no prerequisite is indicated, it will decide not to make that file. Preventing your rule `tests` from being executed.

```
all: main tests

main: $(DEPENDENCY IN SRC and ABC)
    # Recipes (That is the word to describe commands in a make rule)

.PHONY: tests

tests:
     $(MAKE) -C tests
```

Also add the answer by Alex: using `$(MAKE)` is a good practice. And allows your makefiles to work independently from the name of the `make` program. Imagine that you have a distribution where the program is called `xyz-make`.

Comment: There cannot be a file `src/tests` and a directory `src/tests/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
all: main tests

main: $(DEPENDENCY IN SRC and ABC)
   command

tests:
     $(MAKE) -C tests
```

this will unconditionally invoke make of tests on its private subdirectory. Note that usage of special $(MAKE) variable helps to propagate command-line parameters and reduces overhead.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want this Makefile to be aware of the source files in the tests folder.

Perhaps, but you may want to reconsider.  Peter Miller's *[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/)* makes a strong case that one Makefile is all you ever need, or want.  It changed my mind a long time ago.

Comment: downvoting for the dead link